# if blocks in primefaces

Tags: html, if-statement, datatable, primefaces, conditional-statements

I have a bean which contains an int variable.
I want to do something like this:

```
if(value==1)
    <div class='abc'/>
else if(value==2)
    <div class='mno'/>
else
    <div class='xyz'/>
....
```

How do we do this in Primefaces since  doesn't work with datatable?
Could someone please tell me how to achieve this in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="#{bean.style}"
```

Where your getStyle() method in Bean class, returns the desired value. In JSF, do not put logic on xhtml, code it in backing bean and bind it to the ui.